# Windows Embedded Compact 7 - No fonts at all

Tags: windows-embedded-7

I just made an system image using VS2008 Platform Biulder, everything looks fine, but there is one serious problem.

'Font' folder is empty, in my app i cant create fonts at all, any 'new Font(name, size, FontStyle.Regular)' results with creating an Arial font where its size is ignored.

What i have:

In "Core OS\Windows Embedded Compact\Fonts" I have all necessary fonts checked:

```
Web Fonts (Arial, Arial Black, Arial Bold, Courier New, Courier New Bold)
UI (Microsoft San Serif, Segoe UI, Tahoma)
Scripts (Arial, Courier New and so on for Latin, Arabic and Greek)
```

In "\public\common\oak\files\" I have nlscpg.txt with entries for codepages 1250 and 1251

In "Core OS\Windows Embedded Compact\International" I have checked MUI, IMM.

In "Core OS\Windows Embedded Compact\International\Language" I have checked Keyboards, Locale and UI Fonts for various languages (including English).

Now the question is: Why the 'Fonts' folder is empty, what i'm missing in my image configuration?

---

Solved.

I found the solution on my own. there was SYSGEN_GDI_RASTERFONT defined. The only thing need to do was to uncheck one option in Items view.

Answer (score 0):

Compact 7 doesn't support embedded fonts.

read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee489852.aspx) please

Comment: Is that the reason of my problems under .NET CF 3.5?

"new Font(fontName, 96F, FontStyle.Bold)" does not throw any exception, but when I use that font on DrawString, the result visible on screen is incorrect. Size is wrong, font name seems to be ignored.
The same code works fine on WCE 6.0 with .NET CF 2.0